# Gopls only works if I execute vim or vscode with sudo in Macos Big Sur

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vim

For some reason, whenever I execute a Go file with vscode or vim (using coc), I'd get errors such as "could not import fmt", unless I execute both editors with sudo, as shown in images below:

Without sudo:
[image: Without sudo]

With sudo (as you see, I even get documentation about functions):
[image: With sudo]

I'm aware that this might be a permissions issue, but I don't know how to fix this.

This is my go env:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="arm64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/beepstreet/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/beepstreet/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/beepstreet/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/beepstreet/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.16.3/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.16.3/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.3"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch arm64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/45/phdw7kg55g39w7jq9vg95m700000gn/T/go-build1507809915=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the issue. Turns out that my user didn't have write permissions on ~/Library/Caches/go-build/, so I ran the command below and it fixed the issue.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/Library/Caches/go-build/
```

Comment: That's generally the wrong thing to do: you don't want to let everyone and everything write to your caches, what you want is to let *you* write to your caches. Probably one or more of your caches was owned by root, instead of being owned by you. That's typically the result of a trap you set for yourself earlier, when you ran something with `sudo` that you should have run as yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The go-build folder was owned by root by default. Is this a better workaround if I run into this issue again?
`sudo chmod -R 755 ~/Library/Caches/go-build/` to revert the folder permissions to their original state, and
`sudo chown -R myusername ~/Library/Caches/go-build/` to change the owner of the folder

Comment: Well, I'd use 755 for directories and 644 for files (on the assumption that no files should be marked executable) and probably a slightly more targeted `chown` myself, but mostly because I would wonder what files and directories got created/installed here.

Comment: i'm having this exact issue and i think a more targeted `chown` should be the way to go. Having to run it with sudo every time really grind my gears. i'm testing this out the next hours